# Passing SSL certificate and key as string to psycopg2.connect

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, psycopg2

My app is deployed in GCP, I'm trying to make a connection to DB using psycopg2. The SSL certificates and key are not stored as files, so I'll be getting them as strings.

When I try to make a connection by passing the filepath for these certificate pem files, it works.

```
psycopg2.connect(host='hostname',port=1234, connect_timeout=100, database='db', user='user', password='pwd',
sslrootcert="server-cert.pem",
sslcert="client-cert.pem",
sslkey="key.pem")
```

But when I pass certificates and key as strings, it doesn't work. It gives an error

> FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate\nconnection to
> server at "hostname", port 1234 failed

```
SERVER_CERT = """-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nxxxxxx\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"""
CLIENT_CERT = """-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nxxxxxx\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"""
KEY = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxn-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""
psycopg2.connect(host='hostname',port=1234, connect_timeout=100, database='db', user='user', password='pwd',
sslrootcert=SERVER_CERT,
sslcert=CLIENT_CERT,
sslkey=KEY)
```

I also tried using ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(CERT) and RSA.importKey(KEY), but it still fails.
Is there a way to pass string instead of files? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried passing absolute paths instead of relative for the certificates? Usually they are stored in `~/.ssh/key.pem` and not right next to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same situation a couple of hours ago. What I did to resolve this is creating the files in python with the value of the variable:

```
cert = """cert"""
file = open("cert.txt","w")
file.write(cert)
file.close()
```

And then, just pass the path to the psycopg2 connection.